# How does Apache Cordova and ionic framework interact native-ly?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to find out how does *Apache Cordova & Ionic Framework* work?

I searched all over the internet and all I get is, 
it is a wrapper around *html/css/js* and it uses the native *web view* to interact with native feature. But, you still deploy the native-ly. (That means .apk for *Android*, e.g.)

But, what I'm interested in is

- Is Apache Cordova and Ionic Framework entirely written in javascript?
- How do they interact with native mobile platform?
- Does cordova/ionic get bundled with .apk file to *mediate between the native web view and source code*?

I believe what I'm interested in bit of low level detail. 
If anybody could shed some light or point me to the resource (which I couldn't find) , it'd be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/index.html) provides a basic native app responsible for:

- Displaying a Webview (UIWebkit by default for iOS, but you can switch to WKWebkit using a *plugin*. For Android, the "android browser" webview is used up to Android 4.4. From Android 5 (API 21), the webview is basically Chrome for Android).
- Allowing the JavaScript running into this webview to "call" (execute) native code thanks to [Cordova *plugins*](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html#native-interfaces). This is possible because system Webviews can interact with native code.

Ionic Framework (v1) is made of HTML, JavaScript and CSS (v2 is developed in TypeScript, which is a typed superset of JavaScript). The version 1 relies on AngularJS as a frontend JavaScript framework and helps developers writing "native-like" webapps by providing features like Gestures management, Infinite scrolling, Layouts (Menu, Tabs, Lists...), etc. The version 2 relies on Angular 2 and provides additional components (Date picker, Split panel...) and features (Ionic Native, a JavaScript API which tends to "standardize" the way you use Cordova *plugins*).

Ionic can be used without Cordova, if you simply want to create a web app (this is still HTML, JavaScript, and CSS). Cordova allows you to put this web app into a native shell. When an hybrid app (Cordova, the plugins you installed, and your web app) is bundled into an .ipa or an .apk, the html/javascript/css codes are moved into a specific folder, where Cordova expects to find an index.html (by default) to load in the Webview.

PS: My english is not perfect but I'd be glad to give more details if a point is not clear.

---

EDIT:

> Please can you answer my specific questions in my post?

Sure!

- **Apache Cordova** is made of JavaScript and Native code. See projects like [cordova-android](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android) (JavaScript + Java), [cordova-ios](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios) (JavaScript + Objective-C). Each mobile operating system has a dedicated "platform". When you start a new Cordova project, most of the time, the first operation you do is `cordova platform add <platform>` (iOS, Android...). These are the codes being loaded. **Ionic Framework** is a "pure-web" framework, made of HTML, JavaScript and CSS.
- Apache Cordova interacts with native mobile platform as any native app: using the system APIs. The webview can interact with both your web app (of course) and the native code, thanks to platform-specific "bridges" (the native code embedded in cordova-android, cordova-ios, cordova-windows, allows that). You **have to** write a plugin in order to call native code from your JavaScript. For Android, it consists in extending the `CordovaPlugin` class and overriding the method `execute` (for instance: [cordova-plugin-splashscreen](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/blob/2eb78b37242dda30cac201c5b97d6ef52722018e/src/android/SplashScreen.java#L159)).
- The .apk (android) or .ipa (iOS) generated by `cordova build` (if you're using the [cordova-cli](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli)) gathers together both the native shell (cordova-android for Android, cordova-ios for iOS) and your webapp. At startup, the main activity/view of Cordova is instantiated, loads the webview, which itself loads your webapp.

Comment: Thanks that's a great info. One last question, I installed cordova using npm, but I do not see any `native` executables (dll), I only see bunch of javascripts. Where is it located on windows?

Comment: @ZammyPage The cordova CLI is written in JavaScript, that's why you won't find any executable. Node.js is responsible for executing this javascript code :).

Comment: I mean when you do `cordova platform add <platform>`, it has to add some native code written in java/objective-C right for each platform?

Comment: Yes it does. You can find it in the folder platforms/ios and platforms/android, after running `platform add ios` or `android`. This is the same code that you can find in the projects cordova-android and cordova-ios I talked about.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking I would see bunch of `.jar files` in platform folder for android for `native codes`, but there seems to be none. This is the source of my confusion, where is the native code. :)

Comment: if you did run `cordova platform add android` in a cordova project, you can find .java files in platforms/android/CordovaLib and platforms/android/src (paths are more or less similar for iOS, with .m and .h files (Objective-C)).